# Set the default year selected using Pickadate.js

Tags: jquery, pickadate

I'm working on a small project with a [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) plugin.

On the default year, the default selected year is the greatest of all option.
Eg: using setting the year like `1910 to 2012`, the default selected is `2012` and when we click on the select box the selected year which is 2012 is located at the bottom of list.

I tweaked the display and sorted the option list and now when I click on the year selectbox, the years are displayed in descending order but the default selected value is always picking the last option which is the last in the list.

I tried to change the selected value for 2012, so that when I click on the selectbox, the first entry would be 2012 and scroll down to select other year... Not scroll up.

I'm trying this one out to meet User experience.

What I tried so far:

```
onRender: function() {
  $('.picker__select--year option').val('2012').change();
}
```

The issue here is that the seleted value is 2012 and it breaks the sorting of the years. And when I check the console it gives exceeds jquery error.

Settings:

```
min: new Date(1910,1,1),
max: new Date(2012,11,31),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

new Pikaday().gotoYear(2012)

Basically add the gotoYear() funtion at the end with the preferred year.

Comment: I was looking at their website's API, I don't see that function. Is it undocumented?

Comment: Sorry for the late, please check https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday , and search for gotoyear()